# SQL Server Update Where clause performance with clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an update query like below to update AccessDate only when the current date is less then the passed one. The table has a clustered index on Id.

Is there any use to have another non clustered index on Id, AccessDate?

```
Update Person
Set AccessDate = @NewAccessDate
Where Id = @Id
And AccessDate < @NewAccessDate
```

Comment: Out of interest - How many records are you expecting to be updated and how often are the updates to be made?

Comment: You can try creating an index to see whether it makes any difference.

Comment: Without knowing some details on number of records per unique Id it is difficult to say. Can give us COUNT(distinct id) and COUNT(*)?

Comment: around 7Million records on both. Its a unique index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under most circumstances, I would say that the update would be faster without the index.  The key consideration is that the index itself would also need to be updated by the statement.

The one mitigating factor is when each `id` has lots and lots of `AccessDate`s, and very, very few that are less than `@NewAccessdate`.  For instance, if there were 10,000 rows per id and only 1 matched the condition, then updating the index is probably faster than scanning all the access dates.

Or, similarly, if most `id`s had no matching records for the `WHERE` clause.

I'm not sure what the cutoff value is for when one is better or not -- it would depend on other factors, such as your hardware and the number of records per page.  But given that there is a trade-off, you are probably safe not putting in the index.